# Returning array shows null

Tags: c#

My app navigate to the something like below, I can't control this as this return from another app which I am working on a plugin.

http://myapp.com/MyController?url=myUrl.com&ids%5B%5D=6085620807&ids%5B%5D=6085620743

I am trying to get those Ids pushed back to my View e.g.

```
public ActionResult MyController(string url, string[] ids) {
    Response.Write("<input id='url' value='" + url + "'>");
    Response.Write("<input id='orderIds' value='" + ids + "'>");
    return View();
}
```

All I've got is null ids, retrieving url alright. Any ideas on how to get this works will be appreciated.

Regards,

Comment: you need to pass index with array like ids[0] and ids[1] . also refer https://haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx/ for posting list / array to controller

Comment: How the array of ids generated in query string? I think you need to do something like `ids= string.Join("&ids=", arrayofids)}` on the source link, or use customized model binder to do so.

Comment: Thanks for your comments, I have edit the original post. I can't control how the array passed as I receive that directly from the source app which I am working on a plugin. Basically, I click on a link from their app, it redirect to my controller with those parameters.

Comment: @Ollie square brackets are unsafe and should not be used in URLs. See [this](https://perishablepress.com/stop-using-unsafe-characters-in-urls/)

Comment: Sorry guys, actually now I've got this. &ids%5B%5D=6085620743&ids%5B%5D=6085620615. Any ideas?

Comment: Sorry guys, figured out that you can use Request.QueryString["ids[]"] to get the values. Thanks anyway for all the response. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

your controller code is correct.

```
public string test(string[] ids)
    {
        string t = string.Empty;
        foreach(string s in ids)
        {
            t = t + s;
        }
        return t;
    }
```

you need to pass index for array for model binder to identify it.
for example url
www.example.com/test?ids[0]=yourfirstvalue will return yourfirstvalue as output.

but you should consider to bind complex object if you are expecting more items in ids array.

refer haacked.com/archive/2008/10/23/model-binding-to-a-list.aspx for detail

Comment: Thanks please see comments above

Comment: This is not correct, you do not need to pass the index. Actually it will not work like that.

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have this URL:

```
http://myapp.com/MyController?url=myUrl.com&ids=6085620807&ids=6085620743
```

Then you need to bind with this action method:

```
public ActionResult MyController(string url, string[] ids)
{
    // other stuff
    return View();
}
```

You can utilize custom model binder class inherited from `DefaultModelBinder` to get string array component:

```
public class StringArrayModelBinder : DefaultModelBinder
{
    public override object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        var value = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(bindingContext.ModelName);
        if (value == null || string.IsNullOrEmpty(value.AttemptedValue))
        {
            return null;
        }

        return value
            .AttemptedValue
            // use .Split() here if you want to split by particular character(s)
            .ToArray();
    }
}
```

Afterwards, you can apply model binder for certain array of string as argument:

```
public ActionResult MyController(string url, [ModelBinder(typeof(StringArrayModelBinder))] string[] ids)
{
    Response.Write("<input id='url' value='" + url + "'>");
    foreach (string id in ids)
    {
        Response.Write("<input id='orderIds[" + id + "]' value='" + id + "'>");
    }

    return View();
}
```

Or you can apply custom model binder class globally by registering it in `Application_Start` method:

```
protected void Application_Start()
{
    ModelBinders.Binders.Add(typeof(string[]), new StringArrayModelBinder());
}
```

Comment: You do not need a custom binder. It will work without that but the URL should not contain square brackets.

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the brackets from your url, remove the *controller* word (unless you have the controller word duplicated in the name of your controller), and include the action like this:

http://myapp.com/My/test?url=myUrl.com&ids=6085620807&ids=6085620743

The Routing engine will look for a controller named *My* plus the word *Controller* and then find the action  that takes 2 arguments: one string named *url* and one array of integers named *ids*.

Above URL will work with this controller and action:

```
public class MyController{
public string test(string url, string[] ids){...}
}
```